# Sonar rule to report the use of Objects.isNull() and Objects.nonNull() in if-then statements

Tags: java, sonarqube, static-analysis

The Javadoc for the methods [`Objects.isNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) and [`Objects.nonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) clearly state their purpose. e.g.

> This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::nonNull)

But I see developers starting to use these methods within `if-then` statements more frequently. e.g.

```
if (Objects.isNull(foo)) {
  foo = new Foo();
}

if (Objects.nonNull(bar)) {
  bar.doSomething();
}
```

I guess it is subjective as to whether these new methods are cleaner/easier to read than traditional `==` and `!=` operators.

For those of us that are not fans of this (e.g. using these functions outside of the purpose for which they were designed for), is there a Sonar rule that reports this?

Comment: "*I guess it is subjective as to whether these new methods are cleaner/easier to read than traditional `==` and `!=` operators.*" Nah, it's not subjective. The operators are objectively better. The JavaDocs of those methods specifically state their intended purpose "**This method exists to be used as a Predicate**, `filter(Objects::isNull)`"

Comment: I don’t remember what tools Sonar uses under the hood, but [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/) certainly can flag such a grossly inappropriate use of those methods.

Comment: @Michael I am trying very hard to be diplomatic and focus just on the Sonar rule :-)

Comment: You can check all the rules supported at https://rules.sonarsource.com/java.